# Is there Jenkins or other open-source CI for a distributed system?

Tags: jenkins, service, docker, continuous-integration, distributed-computing

I have a set of stateful services that compose a distributed system. Each one has a Docker file that can build it and run its unit tests. I need to check how they interact with each other in a distributed manner. To run tests, I need to:

- Be able to run multiple Docker files at the same time on different nodes that would be considered a single test run.
- Be able to set barriers in commands execution order of each Docker file. In other words, assuming all Docker files run simultaneously I need to be sure that all files have finished stage `X` before starting stage `Y`.
- Be able to stop on failure of any node.

Is there a Jenkins plugin/extension for such operations, or is there any other system or approach that could solve such problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use gitlab and gitlab-ci with autoscale,

this is supported out of the box, see [autoscale runners Gitlab-CI](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/autoscale.md) which uses [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/) with drivers to automatic deploy resources as needed, even on digital ocean.

And you describe your build and tests in the .gitlab-ci.yml:

- defining the different stages, (build, test1 .... )
- where all builds/tests per stage have to finish before moving to the next stage
- and per stage all run parallel, depending on availleble resources of course.

see my simple docker pipeline [here](https://gitlab.com/dgoo2308/docker_env_test/pipelines/4391805).

**REMARK 1:** When confidentiality is an issue, you can

- a. create a private repository on gitlab
- b. host gitlab on your own server*

**REMARK 2:** When code is hosted somewhere else (e.g. github), you can push it to gitlab on every commit to initiate the build pipeline.

*If you would need a professional to setup such a project, you can contact me, but that would be outside the scope of this question/answer*

Answer (score 0):

CloudBees (team behind Jenkins) puts a lot of effort in Docker support in Jenkins 2: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/docker-workflow/

In my opinion is still a little bit immature, but it's step in good direction.

I prefer gitlab-ci (https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/). It's extremely easy to use and rock solid stable. Unfortunately for me tight version control system integration (you have to put your code into GitLab if you would like to use Gitlab-CI) is a show stopper (have to keep my code on Github).

Also you may consider some SaaS products i.e:
https://travis-ci.org/
https://buddybuild.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could always write a bash or powershell script that Jenkins could execute to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Start by moving your integration test outside of your Docker build step. Unit tests could still run there, but I'd prefer to do those separately, outside of the container to minimize how much test code is inside the built image.

For the multi-container integration tests, they need to run them after a `docker run` rather than a `docker build`. That allows you to give each container a name for dns connectivity and control the order of when each test is run. You could even store each test as a docker-compose.yml and process the results.

With the tests separated from the image build, you can add the tests as a step in a Jenkins pipeline to give you the ability to run parts in parallel and wait on each stage for completion before continuing.